# Oracle merge into for when match update and then delete is removing all row

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Below is the data i have. I need duplicate row to be removed but parallely update last update user id and last update time stamp.

There are 3 more column below like Primary Key which is unique and Last Update timestamp and last update user Id.

[image]

When executing the below query it is deleting all 8 rows instead of 4.
I am not able to identify what is wrong in the query,

```
merge into TestTable tgt
using (select ID,
              Date,AMT,
              Currency,
              Value,
              count(*) over (partition by ID, Date, AMT,Currency,Value ) grp_count,
              row_number() over (partition by ID, Date, AMT,Currency,Value order by ID) rn
     from TestTable 
)src
--      where rn > 1) src
on (tgt.ID = src.ID  and src.rn = 2) 
when matched then
    update set  tgt.LastUpdtUser= 'testing',tgt.LastUpdateTime = SYSDATE
    where src.rn = 2
    delete where src.rn = 2;
```

Can anyone please advice. I just need 4 rows to be deleted which has RN = 2 and the row with RN = 1 should have updated timestamp.

Also in real database there are many non duplicate records also. We dont want anything to do in those.

Comment: Shouldn't your update where clause be `where src.rn = 1`?

Comment: yes it got modified when i was pasting here, but point is delete is not happening here. Its removing all 8 rows when it should only delete 4.

Comment: But `(tgt.ID = src.ID  and src.rn = 2)` will prevent rows with `rn = 1` to be selected and thus be candidates for update, no?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are asking

It looks as though you want to delete identical entries having (ID, Date, AMT,Currency,Value)

If so, you can make use of deleting duplicate as follows

```
delete
from TestTable a
where a.rowid in 
(
    select b.rowid
    from 
    (
        select row_number() over (partition by ID, Date1, AMT,Currency1,Value
                                  order by ID) rn,
        rowid
        from TestTable  
    )b
    where b.rn<>1  
)
```

Here is dbfiddle link with a full example.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=572c0aab871a6d1f9c65c4f67da16099

Comment: In the merge query, It deletes everything, since the condition you have specified matches with all of the rows -->on (tgt.ID = src.ID  and src.rn = 2). Here you are saying match all records in Tgt, whose ID matches with the src_block which has rn=2. And since all of your rows have duplicate entries there is always a record with rn=2 for each of the partitioned clause

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way:

```
delete from testtable 
where rowid in (    
    SELECT rowid FROM testtable a
WHERE rowid > ANY
(SELECT rowid FROM testtable b
WHERE a.id = b.id
));
```

This will delete all duplicate rows. You can then update what is left with last update user and last update time.

Let me know if that works out better for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to remove duplicate rows, whilst updating the remaining row.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
MERGE INTO testtable tgt
  USING (SELECT ROWID r_id,
                ID,
                dt,
                amt,
                currency,
                VALUE,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, dt, amt, currency, VALUE) grp_count,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, dt, amt, currency, VALUE ORDER BY lastupdttime) rn
         FROM   testtable) src
  ON (tgt.rowid = src.r_id and src.grp_count > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.lastupdtuser = 'z',
             tgt.lastupdttime = SYSDATE
  DELETE WHERE src.rn > 1;
```

In order to delete rows via a merge, you have to update them first. My merge statement gets all rows that have more than 1 row in the group and updates all the rows, before deleting any that aren't the first row.

I changed the order by in the row_number() function to use lastupdttime (because this way, the order is the same across each time you run the statement, although ultimately it doesn't really matter), and I also join on the rowid of each row, as this is an easy way to identify a row in the absence of a useful primary or unique key. You could update the join to be on the primary/unique key if there is one.